# Соединить сигналами 3 формы

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть три формы. По нажатию кнопки на первой форме появляется вторая. По нажатию кнопки на второй форме появляется третья. По нажатию кнопки на третьей форме передаётся информация на первую форму.

Вопрос можно ли сделать передать информацию с помощью сигналов и слотов, но при этом не таскать с собой указатель на первую форму?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можно первую форму (например, QMainWindow) сделать владельцем (через агрегацию) двух других виджетов и в конструкторе (или любом другом методе, типа `init()`, `prepareUi()`) сделать все необходимые коннекты.

Comment: Т.е. при создании первой формы создавать ещё и две другие, объявив их членами класса первой формы?

Comment: Private-членами можно обьявить указатели, в списке инициализации создать, передав this, в конструкторе настроить сигналы-слоты.